# What does the # operator do in macros?

Tags: c, macros

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define foo(x, y) #x #y

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", foo(k, l));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
`kl`

I know that ## does concatenation. From the output it seems that `#` also does concatenation.
Am I correct?

If I am correct then what is the difference between `##` operator and `#` operator?

Comment: do gcc -E yourfile.c  and see what preprocessing was done

Comment: @JensGustedt: You linked a duplicate :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla, yes I know, but a duplicate of a duplicate is not necessarily an exact duplicate for the original question. The one I linked is really almost identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` turns the argument into a string. So `foo(k, l)` becomes `"k" "l"`, which is the same as `"kl"` because in C multiple string literals that are directly next to each other are treated as a single string literals.

If `#` did concatenation, your printf call would become `printf("%s\n", kl);` which would produce an error about `kl` not being defined.

Answer (score 2):

`#` *stringifies* the parameter. See http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cpp/cpp.html#SEC15

`##` *concatenates* strings. See http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cpp/cpp.html#SEC16

Answer (score 1):

`##` concatenates the two arguments, `#` quotes ("Stringification") them. So the compiler sees:

```
printf("%s\n", "k" "l");
```

If you use GCC, use `-E` to see the output of the preprocessor.

This question contains details about concatenation of string literals: [Implementation of string literal concatenation in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142630/implementation-of-string-literal-concatenation-in-c-and-c)