# String concatenation with a space

Tags: c, string

In K&R, I saw an example where a string can be concatenated with a space"

```
char *s = "abc" "foo";
printf("%s", s); // prints "abcfoo"
```

How is space string concatenation different from using strcpy and strcat?

Comment: Fairly sure that's only for string literals.

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenation of two string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120944/concatenation-of-two-string-literals) , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142630/implementation-of-string-literal-concatenation-in-c-and-c?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjacent string literal are concatenated by the pre-processor. From the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `5.1.1.2` *Translation phases* paragraph *6*:

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated

so it creates one string literal as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
    char *s = "abc" " " "foo";

BTW: it is not concatenation per se, it is just a method for initialising a string with a concatenation of a bunch of literals.